# Getting problem in accessing web cam

Tags: java

I have written code in Java to access web cam,and to save image...
I am getting following exceptions :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at SwingCapture.(SwingCapture.java:40)
 at SwingCapture.main(SwingCapture.java:66)

how to remove this exceptions.

here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
```

import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.media.*;
import javax.media.format.*;
import javax.media.util.*;
import javax.media.control.*;
import javax.media.protocol.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.*;

public class SwingCapture extends Panel implements ActionListener 
{
  public static Player player = null;
  public CaptureDeviceInfo di = null;
  public MediaLocator ml = null;
  public JButton capture = null;
  public Buffer buf = null;
  public Image img = null;
  public VideoFormat vf = null;
  public BufferToImage btoi = null;
  public ImagePanel imgpanel = null;

public SwingCapture() 
  {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setSize(320,550);

```
imgpanel = new ImagePanel();
capture = new JButton("Capture");
capture.addActionListener(this);


String str1 = "vfw:iNTEX IT-308 WC:0";
String str2 = "vfw:Microsoft WDM Image Capture (Win32):0";
di = CaptureDeviceManager.getDevice(str2);
ml = di.getLocator();

try 
{
  player = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(ml);
  player.start();
  Component comp;

  if ((comp = player.getVisualComponent()) != null)
  {
    add(comp,BorderLayout.NORTH);
  }
  add(capture,BorderLayout.CENTER);
  add(imgpanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    Frame f = new Frame("SwingCapture");
    SwingCapture cf = new SwingCapture();

```
f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
  public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
  playerclose();
  System.exit(0);}});

f.add("Center",cf);
f.pack();
f.setSize(new Dimension(320,550));
f.setVisible(true);
```

}

public static void playerclose() 
  {
    player.close();
    player.deallocate();
  }

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
  {
    JComponent c = (JComponent) e.getSource();

```
if (c == capture) 
{
  // Grab a frame
  FrameGrabbingControl fgc = (FrameGrabbingControl)
  player.getControl("javax.media.control.FrameGrabbingControl");
  buf = fgc.grabFrame();

  // Convert it to an image
  btoi = new BufferToImage((VideoFormat)buf.getFormat());
  img = btoi.createImage(buf);

  // show the image
  imgpanel.setImage(img);

  // save image
  saveJPG(img,"\test.jpg");
}
```

}

class ImagePanel extends Panel 
  {
    public Image myimg = null;

```
public ImagePanel() 
{
  setLayout(null);
  setSize(320,240);
}

public void setImage(Image img) 
{
  this.myimg = img;
  repaint();
}

public void paint(Graphics g) 
{
  if (myimg != null) 
  {
    g.drawImage(myimg, 0, 0, this);
  }
}
```

}

public static void saveJPG(Image img, String s)
  {
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g2 = bi.createGraphics();
    g2.drawImage(img, null, null);

```
FileOutputStream out = null;
try
{ 
  out = new FileOutputStream(s); 
}
catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException io)
{ 
  System.out.println("File Not Found"); 
}

JPEGImageEncoder encoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(out);
JPEGEncodeParam param = encoder.getDefaultJPEGEncodeParam(bi);
param.setQuality(0.5f,false);
encoder.setJPEGEncodeParam(param);

try 
{ 
  encoder.encode(bi); 
  out.close(); 
}
catch (java.io.IOException io) 
{
  System.out.println("IOException"); 
}
```

}

}

Comment: So that's the line `ml = di.getLocator();`, which is preceded by `di = CaptureDeviceManager.getDevice(str2);`.  I guess `CaptureDeviceManager.getDevice` returned `null`, probably for a reason listed in its API docs.

Comment: String str2 = "vfw:Microsoft WDM Image Capture (Win32):0";
this is for MS Windows,
I am using Ubuntu Linux..
I think there must be replacement for this line in Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using built in web cam most of the time it shows errors. You can try with external web cam.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is somewhat messy, but did you make sure to specify that your Frame had a borderlayout set? I've been through this issue many times. Try explicitly stating this.Layout = new BorderLayout();. If the problem persists let me know and ill try to help.

Comment: Actually CaptureDeviceManager.getDevice returned null
thats why this exception occurs.
I am not getting why it is giving this exception.
I am doing this program in Eclipse on Linux platform.
Can you help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

I have ENTER Web Camera Model No: E-1.3MPIR what should be the argument for CaptureDeviceManager.getDevice()